# I want to prevent another element position from decreasing when "display: block;" width mouse-over,

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

About [this code.](http://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/gHnGD)

---

**default**
[image: defaulte]

---

**I would like to customize this way**
[image: I would like to customize this wayre]

---

**initial state**

▼CSS

```
@media (max-width: 700px) {
  .transformer-tabs ul {
    border-bottom: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
  }
```

---

**When I mouse over**

▼CSS

```
  .transformer-tabs ul.open a {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
  }
```

---

**I added the z-index as below. However, I could not get the expected effect.**

▼CSS

```
  .transformer-tabs ul.open a {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    z-index: 10;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
@media (max-width: 700px) {
  .transformer-tabs ul {
    border-bottom: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    width:100%
  }
  .tabs{
    position:relative;
  }
}
```

I hope Here Is Your Solution???

Answer (score 0):

Here your are. If you don't use boostrap, try to use position fixed.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Case</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
      </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Page 1 <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
      </ul>      
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
  <p>abc</p>
  <p>abc</p>
  <p>abc</p>
  <p>abc</p>
  <p>abc</p>
  <p>abc</p>
  <p>abc</p>
  <p>abc</p>
  <p>abc</p>
  <p>abc</p>
  <p>abc</p>
  <p>abc</p>
  <p>abc</p>
  <p>abc</p>
  <p>abc</p>
  <p>abc</p>
  <p>abc</p>
  <p>abc</p>
  <p>abc</p>
  <p>abc</p>
  <p>abc</p>
  <p>abc</p>
  <p>abc</p>
  <p>abc</p>
  <p>abc</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's not z-index, it's a matter of postiton. It was helpful